# Google maps panorama street view

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have integrated google maps panorama street view in my new project, when i am  searching using this address( just an example) "1146 Second Ave, New York, NY, United States", i can see inside of the building.But when i am search the same address from here https://maps.google.co.in/  google is showing out side of the building.
my question is , Is there any way to get the same result what google is showing ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=1146%20Second%20Ave,%20New%20York,%20NY,%20United%20States)?

Comment: view:source on the page.

Comment: Hey! that is what I need! thanks. Can you point out the lines of code that make the difference between inside and street view? I have a new york address that shows the inside of a Chinese Restaurant: 273 Bowery, Manhattan, New York when using Google Maps API.